# How to prove that the position operator in momentum is $i\hbar \partial/\partial p$ - One Missing Sign

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, fourier-transform

> I am trying to prove that the position operator in momentum space is  $i\hbar \partial/\partial p$ but my derivation is missing one sign. Can someone spot the error?

Start with

$$<\hat x> = 
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi^*(x)  x  \psi(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

Taking the fourier transform of both $\psi(x)$

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \psi^*(\bar k_x) e^{i\bar k_xx} \, \mathrm{d} \bar k_x x \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(k_x) e^{-i k_xx} \mathrm{d} k_x  \mathrm{d} x 
$$

Taking integration by parts on the right most integral yields

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \psi^*(\bar k_x) e^{i\bar k_xx} \, \mathrm{d} \bar k_x x * \frac{1}{ix} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i k_xx} \frac {\partial \psi(k_x)}{\partial k_x} \mathrm{d} k_x  \mathrm{d} x 
$$

We see the middle term gets canceled out.

Now using the following identity

$$
\delta(k_x-\bar k_x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-ix(k_x-\bar k_x)} \, \mathrm{d} x
$$

we arrive at

$$
\frac{1}{i} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \psi^*(\bar k_x) \delta(k_x-\bar k_x) \mathrm{d} \bar k_x  \frac {\partial \psi(k_x)}{\partial k_x} \mathrm{d} k_x 
$$

$$
\frac{1}{i}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \psi^*(k_x) \frac {\partial \psi(k_x)}{\partial k_x} \mathrm{d} k_x 
$$

Very lastly, we use the following identity

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial k_x} = \frac{\hbar \partial}{\partial p_x}$$

We prove

$$
\frac{\hbar}{i} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \psi^*(k_x) \frac {\partial \psi(k_x)}{\partial p_x} \mathrm{d} k_x 
$$

So

$$ x = \frac{\hbar \partial}{i\partial p_x}$$

So close, not quite right. Because the actual answer is $$ x = \frac{-\hbar \partial}{i\partial p_x}$$ or $$ x = \frac{i\hbar \partial}{\partial p_x}$$

Can someone spot the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: The reason for the difference in sign w.r.t. the momentum operator is due to the fact that the Fourier transform and its inverse have an opposite sign in the exponential.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80357/2451

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [check-my-work questions are off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to prove that the position operator in momentum is iℏ∂/∂p

Apply the following useful result.

If

$$F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-ikx}dx$$

then

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)e^{-ikx}dx  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\left(i\frac{\partial}{\partial k} e^{-ikx}\right)dx = i\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-ikx}dx = i\frac{\partial}{\partial k}F(k)$$

Comment: isn't that true that we don't have to solve home problems?

Comment: @Sofia, isn't it true that this isn't (remotely) a solution to the problem but just a well known result from Fourier analysis?

Comment: @Sofia, please get a grip.    http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+a+grip

Comment: @Sofia, I don't have the slightest idea what you're talking about.

Comment: the law says that home exercises should not be solved in entirety, just be given *guide lines*. This law should be respected by everybody.

Comment: @Sofia, in my judgement, my answer is simply a helpful hint.  If it is your judgement that my answer constitutes an entire solution, be aware that I substitute no one's judgement for my own.

Comment: Alfred, in one of my answers I said *bye*. Let's close this issue. I only called your attention on the law. And despite the fact that it seems to me that you solved his exercise, I don't ask you to submit to my judgement. Let's close this issue, you are busy, I am busy. Let's put an end.

Comment: @Sofia, you started this nonsense and I've called you out on it.  This seems to be a pattern of yours; making some absurd claim and then running away from the push back.  That's not going to fly with me.

Comment: how aggressive you are. ***Please take a grip***, calm down. Aggresivity won't go with me. I don't run away. What you expected, that I begin to insult you as you insult me? I still consider that you fully answered the question, but the issue was discussed enough, and I hope that you'll be more careful in the future. My comments aren't **nonsense**, you please don't play the psychologist with me - you don't have the possibility to pattern me, whatever you dislike is not **absurd**. And with this, the issue is ***closed***.

Comment: @Sofia, any reasonable person reading these comments is likely to come to the conclusion that the one losing one's calm is *you*.  Why do you diminish yourself like this?

Comment: Everybody just calm down...1. This isn't even remotely a homework question, I was reading a book on my trip to Alberta and thought it would be fun to prove this, 2. The question is trivial, I'm missing a sign somewhere, 3. I needed to see steps because the result is well known, so this answer is helpful