# Does a free electron, one that's not either in an atom or a wire, have an associated wave-function?

Tags: wavefunction, electrons

Would a free electron, one that's not either in an atom or moving through a wire, but moving through empty space on its own, have an associated wave-function? Or, is an electron described as a wave-function only when inside an atom?

And if the type of free electron I'm describing does have a wave-function, how can it when the electron wouldn't be in an orbital within an atom?

Comment: Free particles do have wave functions. Common ways of defining a free particle wave function is either as a plane wave, in which case the position is completely unknown, but the momentum is precisely determined, or a gaussian wave packet, which is the evolution of a free particle which had an initially well known position that is becoming increasingly uncertain.

Comment: CuriousOne -- That definitely helps clarify things for me. Thank you once again. If you don't mind my asking, how about inside a wire when an electron is either in AC or DC current? In this case would the idea of an associated wave-function be eliminated?

Comment: That's a lot more complicated. Electrons in metals are reasonably well described by electronic band structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure. With DC current flowing one needs to have an additional model for scattering on phonons and impurities and with AC current there is also coupling to the electromagnetic field.

Comment: I just took a look at that page. I see what you mean..a lot more to it. Will definitely keep me busy later tonight..

Comment: Might I add that the free particle wave function as described by a plane wave cannot be normalised.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a free particle has a wavefunction. If it has sharp momentum $p$, it is given by the plane wave
$$ \psi_p(x) = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}px}$$
which might look a bit strange, because it is non-normalizable/not square-integrable, but that should not be all too troubling - no momentum uncertainty at all is rather unphysical, after all. The general wavefunction of a free particle is a square-integrable superposition of these plane waves. As to why such non-normalizable states arise, read [Rod Vance's answer on rigged Hilbert spaces and their connection to scattering states](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90261/50583).

Electrons are *always* quantum objects, whether they are bound or not, and thus must always be represented as a quantum state, which is almost always representable by a wavefunction.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** need of a potential for the Schrödinger equation to have a solution, namely
$$
i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} |\psi\rangle = H |\psi\rangle
$$
does possess solutions even when the Hamiltonian contains no potential. Questions of normalisability may arise, but that is another point (and can anyway be solved by expanding in Fourier terms).

> *And if the type of free electron I'm describing does have a wave-function,   how can it when the electron wouldn't be in an orbital within an atom?*

You seem to have a little odd idea of what a wave function is, probably due to some odd-written books in chemistry which associate the wave function to some sort of orbital cloud. That is by **no** means what the wave function is. Rather it is the representation on the position basis  $\langle x|\psi\rangle$ of the solution of the Schrödinger equation above.