# Interpretation of the Dirac-measure property

Tags: dirac-delta-distributions

First and foremost, apologies in advance for using an abuse of notation by placing the Dirac measure inside an integral. But given the circumstances, I have no choice.

This is essentially a word by word copy of an interpretation given on page 1 of these [Berkeley notes](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/delta.pdf):

> The important property of the delta function is the following relation
>   $$\displaystyle\int f(t) \delta(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = f(0)$$  for any
>   function $f(t)$. This is easy to see. First of all, $\delta(t)$
>   vanishes everywhere except when $t = 0$. Therefore, it does not matter
>   what values the function $f(t)$ takes except at $t = 0$. You can then
>   say $f(t)\delta(t) = f(0)\delta(t)$. Then $f(0)$ can be pulled outside
>   the integral because it does not depend on $t$, and you obtain the
>   r.h.s.

Here's the problem, it was my understanding that $$\delta(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & \space \mathrm{for} \space t \ne 0 \\\infty&\ \mathrm{for} \space t = 0 \end{cases} $$ So by my logic this means that $\delta(0)=\infty$ and therefore undefined; which implies that when $t=0$ $$\displaystyle\int f(0) \delta(0) \, \mathrm{d}t = \displaystyle\int f(0) ~\infty \, \mathrm{d}t$$ which is manifestly not true and certainly not equal to $f(0)$.

Clearly I am missing the point of this argument, so if someone would be kind enough to explain it to me I would be most grateful.

Comment: This is a purely mathematical question, so it should be migrated to math.SE. Aside from that, the $\delta$ function is not a function, but a special object called distribution. If you take a look on how they work, things would probably become clearer to you ;-)

Comment: @yuggib It's already come __from__ math SE and no it is not a purely mathematical question

Comment: @yuggib I know it's a distribution, but could you please just answer the question? You clearly know how to explain it, those at math SE do not know how to. That is why they suggested it to be asked here instead. And yes I know that you guys prefer only conceptual questions.

Comment: The Math SE counterpart:http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1465361/

Comment: @user36790 That's right, well spotted, this question just needs a Physics touch. But __please__, don't mark it as 'off topic', as this has happened so many times in the past. I desperately need to understand what is going on with this question.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210552/2451

Comment: The quoted argument is bad. $\delta'(t)$ vanishes everywhere except at $t=0$, however the values of $f$ away from zero *do* matter: usually, $f(t) \delta'(t) \neq f(0) \delta'(t)$. (in fact, $f(t) \delta'(t) = t f'(0) \delta'(t)$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A distribution is not a function, it is a functional acting on (a suitable space of) functions.

In particular, let's consider the [functions of rapid decrease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Its topological dual, $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$, is the space of continuous linear functionals of $\mathscr{S}$, and it is called the space of tempered distributions.

How does a distribution work? It is a map that associates to each $f\in\mathscr{S}$, a complex number. Its action is usually denoted by $(\phi,\cdot)$, where $\phi\in\mathscr{S}'$. The Dirac delta distribution $\delta\in\mathscr{S}'$, is the distribution defined by:
$$(\delta,f)=f(0) \quad, \quad  f\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)\; .$$

Now the rapid decrease functions are dense in the tempered distributions, in a suitable topology (the $\sigma(\mathscr{S}',\mathscr{S})$ one). And there is a natural identification of $f\in\mathscr{S}$ with the corresponding element $\tilde{f}\in\mathscr{S}'$: $\tilde{f}$ is the distribution whose action is defined by
$$(\tilde{f},g)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)g(x)dx\quad ,\quad g\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)\; .$$
So if the $\delta$ distribution was a real function $\delta(x)$ (but it is not!), we could write
$$(\delta,f)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\delta(x)f(x)dx=f(0)\; .$$
This is what it is usually done by physicists, but it is an **abuse of notation**. Another abuse of notation, is to write $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\delta(x)dx=1$. In principle, it is not possible to define the integral of a distribution. However this abuse of notation may be justified as follows:

- It is possible to approximate the delta distribution by rapid decrease functions, since $\mathscr{S}$ is dense in $\mathscr{S}'$. Indeed, given an integrable function $\eta$, such that $\int\eta(x)dx=1$, then
  $$\delta_h(x)=\frac{1}{h^d}\eta\bigl(\tfrac{x}{h}\bigr)$$
  is an approximation of $\delta$, in the sense that
  $$\lim_{h\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\delta_h(x)f(x)dx=f(0)\quad ,\quad f\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)\; .$$
  Since, in addition,
  $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\delta_h(x)dx=1$$
  uniformly in $h$, it is tempting to conclude that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\delta(x)dx=1$ (but it is not true, since- very roughly speaking -you are not allowed to take the limit inside the integral).

The above type of approximations $\delta_h$, also suggest the "pictorial" representation of $\delta$ as a function (but it is not!) that is zero everywhere, and infinity in zero. However, this is just a pictorial representation (that may be useful, but is not rigorous); so it cannot be used to argue pro or against the notation $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\delta(x)f(x)dx$ (that again is just an abusive notation, and not a rigorously defined integral).